# How to execute code which comes after a section where element is not found in a test method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Suppose, I am testing method which checks whether all links are present on page. Ex :

```
@Test
public void testLinks(){
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("link1"));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("link2"));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("link3"));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("link4"));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("link5"));
}
```

In above code, suppose all links are present except `link3` then test method's execution will stop after throwing error for `link3` but still if I want code to be executed for checking `link4` and `link5`, how can I achieve that using Java?

Comment: You need to determine what it means to "fail" this test then structure your test accordingly. You can: 1) Separate into 5 different tests. 2) Rework `findElement` to include the possibility of OR'd or AND'd queries (depending on your intention). 3) Hack it by catching and rethrowing exceptions as needed (not really a good approach).

Comment: by _"...throwing error..."_ are you referring to an exception?

Comment: @ambigram-maker, yes I'm referring to an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean throwing exceptions.
You can test links one by one in another method which handle exceptions.

```
public void testOne(String link) {
    try {
       driver.findElement(By.linkText(link));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(link+" failed to find");
    }
}

public void test() {
    testOne("link1");
    testOne("link2");
    testOne("link3");
    testOne("link4");
    testOne("link5");
}
```

The `testOne()` method will catch exceptions and print a failed note, and your test method won't be disrupted.

Comment: But then, how will you know if the test failed? This really seems like it should be 5 independent @Test's to me.

Comment: @Jason C yep, but I think this is OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can use TestNg reporter to make your test pass or fail or log4j logs, try this.

```
sResult = "Pass";

public void testOne(String link) {
    try {
       driver.findElement(By.linkText(link));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(link+" failed to find");
       sResult = "Fail";
    }
}

public void test() {
    testOne("link1");
    testOne("link2");
    testOne("link3");
    testOne("link4");
    testOne("link5");
}


if(sResult.equals("Pass")){
            System.out.println("Pass");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Fail");

        }
```